# function that checks if a number is narcisstic or not

Tags: javascript

I run the code multiple times but couldn't find the problem!!

A Narcissistic Number is a positive number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits in a given base. In this Kata, we will restrict ourselves to decimal (base 10).

Your code must return true or false (not 'true' and 'false') depending upon whether the given number is a Narcissistic number in base 10.

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let strDigits = value.toString();
  let power = strDigits.length;
  
  let arrayDigits = strDigits.split('');
  let sum, poweredValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < power; i++){
   poweredValue = Number(arrayDigits[i])**power;
    sum += poweredValue;
  }
  if (sum === value){
    return true;
  }else {
    return false;
  }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the initial value for `sum` as `0`. By default, it's set to `undefined`. And adding something to `undefined` gives `NaN`, and any comparison with `NaN` is always `false`.

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let strDigits = value.toString();
  let power = strDigits.length;

  let arrayDigits = strDigits.split("");
  let sum = 0,
    poweredValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < power; i++) {
    poweredValue = Number(arrayDigits[i]) ** power;
    sum += poweredValue;
  }
  if (sum === value) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assumed that the statement of the form:

```
let x, y =0;
```

initialize `x` and `y` both as 0. But x is still `undefined`.
And type `undefined` + type `number` will evaluate to `NaN` (not a number).
And no number is equal to `NaN`

Just initialize properly:

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let strDigits = value.toString();
  let power = strDigits.length;
  let arrayDigits = strDigits.split('');
  let sum =0, poweredValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < power; i++){
   poweredValue = Number(arrayDigits[i])**power;
    sum += poweredValue;
  }
  if (sum === value){
    return true;
  }else {
    return false;
  }
  };
  
  
  console.log(narcissistic(153));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```js
const n = 153

function action(n) {
  let sum = 0;
  n.toString().split('').forEach(i => {
    sum += parseInt(i)**n.toString().length;  
  })
  return sum == n  
}

console.log(action(n))
```